# How can I change the logout from menu to a normal button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I am new to coding and I have one issue with a code from youtube, is a signin and up tutorial with FireBase. The logout button is set to a menu on the ActionBar and I don't know how to set onClickListener on a TextView to do the same thing.

[The menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQkkP.jpg)

[The TextView I want the ClickListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MICF.jpg)

The menu code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_log, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id  = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_log){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        checkUserStatus();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

If you show me the code and explain it to me it would be amazing. Is all I ask. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you mean, click on text view use `textview.setonclickListener{//do what you want}`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `Button` to your layout xml & give it an `id`.
Example:

```xml
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="Sign Out" />
```

Then in you `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`,
find the button & set a click listener.

```java
Button signOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
signOutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    firebaseAuth.signOut();
                    checkUserStatus();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Signed Out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
            }  
        });
```

Comment: You’re welcome, do Accept the answer if it helped you. :)